# cannot download an image from server with authentication using c# in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

am using following code to download image from server but failed.
am using server authentication please help

```
  private BitmapImage getimage (string uri)
    {


        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);//making a variable webrequest,
        webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");//credential is using for authentication
        using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())//use for stucking problem of button
        {
            using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();
                img.StreamSource = responseStream;
                img.EndInit();
                return img;

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Does it throw any exception ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are closing the response stream before the image is completely downloaded. In order to ensure that it is completely downloaded, you can copy it to an intermediate MemoryStream. Moreover, you will have to set the `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` flag if you want to close the stream immediately after `EndInit`. See the Remarks section in [BitmapImage.StreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) .

```
using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    img.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    img.EndInit();
    return img;
}
```

Alternatively you could delay the closing of the WebResponse until the image has been download completely. BitmapImage provides the `DownloadCompleted` and `DownloadFailed` event handlers for purposes like that. Note that closing the WebResponse also closes the response stream.

```
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
var img = new BitmapImage();
img.DownloadCompleted += (o, e) => webResponse.Close();
img.DownloadFailed += (o, e) => webResponse.Close();
img.BeginInit();
img.StreamSource = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
img.EndInit();
return img;
```